# Modification of DBus /etc/dbus-1/system.conf broke the startup process

Tags: fedora, startup, d-bus

I have modified the file `/etc/dbus-1/system.conf` where I have changed the document to something like that:

```
<listen>tcp:host=localhost,bind=*,port=6667</listen>
<auth>ANONYMOUS</auth>
<allow_anonymous/>
```

The computer passes the grub menu and starts booting fedora. But at a certain point the DELL logo blinks and nothing happens any more. I see the IP appear on the router, but I cannot log in using ssh:

```
ssh: connect to host PRIVATE_IP port 22: Connection refused
```

In summary I think that DBus is broken and I don't manage to make my computer start up.

I am operating a Fedora 32 OS. On a DELL Latitude 5500.

I so strongly wish to simply access the filesystem in order to reset the file to default empty configuration. Would you think of a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was to start fedora on a usb key. Then use the `Disk utility`  to mount the partition containing the root folder of the installed fedora (the one not booting). Then modify the `/etc/dbus-1/system.conf` file and restore it to the default state.